# How do I run ARM/Assembly code using vscode?

Tags: assembly, arm, vscode-extensions

I have 2 courses, one of them uses scheme, or rather Racket, which I have managed to implement in VSCode without too many problems. The second one teaches assembly, they suggest a program to emulate it called `ARMSim#`, which is pretty old.

I would love to start using VSCode and Copilot with my ARM (pretty sure its the 32 bit version but not sure, if anybody knows how to check) but googling wasn't really much help and I could only find instructions on how to run VSCode on an arm device and not the other way around.

Copilot chat said it is possible, haven't tested it yet because I don't really like that it talks about projects, I'm going to have lots of different files with exercises in them so having to do this for each and every one is going to be a pain in the ass.

```
Yes, it is possible to write and run ARM32 assembly code on Visual Studio Code. Here are the steps:

1. Install the "C/C++" extension by Microsoft from the VS Code marketplace. This extension provides language support for C/C++ to Visual Studio Code, including features such as IntelliSense and debugging.

2. Install an ARM cross compiler on your system. For example, you can use the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain. You can download it from the official website and add it to your system's PATH.

3. Install an ARM emulator. For example, you can use QEMU, an open-source machine emulator and virtualizer. This will allow you to run your ARM assembly code on your computer, even if it doesn't have an ARM processor.

4. Configure your tasks.json file in VS Code to use the ARM cross compiler for building your ARM assembly code, and QEMU for running it.

Here's an example of how you might configure your tasks.json file:

{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build ARM assembly",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "arm-none-eabi-as",
            "args": [
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Link ARM assembly",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "arm-none-eabi-ld",
            "args": [
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o"
            ],
            "dependsOn": "Build ARM assembly"
        },
        {
            "label": "Run ARM assembly",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "qemu-arm",
            "args": [
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "dependsOn": "Link ARM assembly"
        }
    ]
}

5. Now you can write your ARM assembly code in a .s file, and use the build task (Terminal -> Run Build Task) to compile and run it.

Please note that the exact configuration may vary depending on your specific ARM chip and development environment.
```

Comment: It seems you need to ask Copilot how to read the VSCode documentation. If you have the ARM toolchain you only need to tell VSCode the commands to invoke (essentially reproducing what you do in a command line). I don't understand why you want to spend hours convincing a text predictor to generate a valid configuration file while you could do that yourself after a 10 min read.

Comment: I don't really know what a toolchain is...also we just started out learning what the arm instructions and really haven't done anything concrete yet, also, didn't really want Copilot to generate the config file, just didn't know what to do even after googling a bunch

Comment: @MargaretBloom sorry to tag you, but could I get an answer?  You missed the point of the entire question.